# Scoped_session has no attribute cursor: Flask-SQLAlchemy session in pd.read_sql

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am switching from the standalone SQLAlchemy package in my Flask app to Flask-SQLAlchemy. Everything went smoothly except for one problem. I cannot use the database session provided by Flask-SQLAlchemy with the `pd.read_sql(...)` method.

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = create_connection_string()
db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)
db.init_app(app)

pd.read_sql(db.session)
```

Executing the above gives the error: `AttributeError: 'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'cursor'`.

In all other places where I am now using the db.session object, it works as expected. This is the only trouble I am having. What am I missing?